# DataTable Maximum Length and Maximum limit of A Cell?

Tags: c#, datatable

I want to read a **.txt** file in **datatable** , i want to know what is the **maximum number of rows** in a **datatable**, and what is **maximum limit(Length of digits or characters) of a cell** in a column.

Answer (score 1):

1st question:-

> The maximum number of rows that a DataTable can store is 16,777,216

2nd question:-

> Each DataColumn has a DataType property that determines the kind of data the DataColumn contains. For example, you can restrict the data type to integers, or strings, or decimals. Because data that is contained by the DataTable is typically merged back into its original data source, you must match the data types to those in the data source.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)